# How to remove "no cents" when spelling out cents less dollar figures in excel?

Tags: excel, numbers, out, spelling

I am being able to spell out dollar number in excel perfectly. But what I dont want is when it spells out "no cents". So let say if I wanted to spell out 24030. It would say Twenty Four Thousand Thirty Dollars and no cents. I want excel only to spell out the cents value only when it is present.

Currently I am spelling out the dollar value using module from the microsoft support website and here is the link http://support.microsoft.com/KB/213360

I would really appreciate if someone could help me in this. Thanks a bunch in advance.

I apologies in advance if this question has already been asked but on my defense I was unable to find the right answer for it. So hopefully some one can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a single line to the end of the **UDF**:

```
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
    Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    ReDim Place(9) As String
    Place(2) = " Thousand "
    Place(3) = " Million "
    Place(4) = " Billion "
    Place(5) = " Trillion "
    ' String representation of amount.
    MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
    ' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
    DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    ' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
    If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
        Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
                  "00", 2))
        MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    End If
    Count = 1
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
        Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
        If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
        If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
            MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
        Else
            MyNumber = ""
        End If
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Select Case Dollars
        Case ""
            Dollars = "No Dollars"
        Case "One"
            Dollars = "One Dollar"
         Case Else
            Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
    End Select
    Select Case Cents
        Case ""
            Cents = " and No Cents"
        Case "One"
            Cents = " and One Cent"
              Case Else
            Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
    End Select
    SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
    SpellNumber = Replace(SpellNumber, " and No Cents", "")
End Function
```

The advantage is that you can always go back to the original functionality by commenting out the single new line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these lines from VBA script:

```
Case ""
    Cents = " and No Cents"
```

Or use this formula on your text:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(" and no cents",A1)),A1,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-13))
```